# Calibrate a FirstPerson movement combination

Tags: mathematics

Given a script that listens for key inputs and checks which keys are pressed, how should I deal with combinations like up and right ?
up will increase local Y velocity and right local Y, but if nothing more is done the player can cheat his speed by advancing diagonally.
I'm sure I have to decompose the vector that is added to the speed and multiply X with a cosinus of the Z axis (the world one ?) and Y with a sinus of the same.
But I end up with a correct strafe only in two directions, it seems that the cos and sin get to zero in the same time on the two others since the motions is close to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize the vector. Normalizing means that your vector length is equal to 1, it doesn't matter where it's pointing.

Python example

```
from mathutils import *
v = Vector((1,1,0.2))

v.normalize()

print(v)
# <Vector (0.7001, 0.7001, 0.1400)>
```

Comment: Thank you merci.